# Are novice questions acceptable?

Tags: support

I've never done any handywork, let alone home improvement projects but I'd like to start so I don't need to hire someone every little thing that needs fixing or installing. However, the description states:

> Home Improvement Stack Exchange is for contractors and (serious) DIY'ers.

Is it acceptable to ask very novice/basics question on this website?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, all home improvement questions are welcome. However, take a look around first, as your question might already have an answer.  Also make sure you're asking a single specific question, as broad questions are difficult to answer in this format.